# How to recognize that a form is in focus through event?

Tags: delphi-2010

In an application, we have multiple forms. Now we want to refresh a form 'X' when user sees the form 'x' either by restoring it from taskbar or with 'alt+tab'. How to recognize this through event.
The events 'OnActivate','OnShow' get called only once when the form is created. So they are not useful here.

Comment: 'OnFocus' event is not available for the form 'X'.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim that the [`TForm.OnActivate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnActivate) and [`TForm.OnShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnShow) events are fired only once per `TForm` instance is not true.

The [`TForm.OnActivate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnActivate) event is fired when a `TForm` window gains input focus for the first time, and afterwards whenever input focus is transferred to that window from another `TForm` window, while the app is in the foreground.

Note that there are also [`TApplication.OnActivate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnActivate) and [`TApplicationEvents.OnActivate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnActivate) events that are fired when your app comes into the foreground for the first time, and afterwards whenever focus moves to another app and then back to your app.

The [`TForm.OnShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnShow) event is fired when a `TForm` window becomes visible for the first time, and afterwards whenever that window becomes hidden and then is reshown.